# Gradle home can not be found - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and Gradle. Everything was working perfectly fine but suddenly Android studio has started to give me the following error when I run the project (no problem in building the project):

`Error running build: Gradle home can not be found`

I'm on a Mac OS X and I have already tried to follow [this article](http://www.cerebro.com.au/2013/08/01/java-gradle-install-gradle-in-mac-osx/) to add Gradle home to my system PATH variable.

I am also assuming this happened after my latest update to the Android Studio.

Can anyone please help me figure out what might be causing this as I have tried to search a lot with no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: add GRADLE_HOME to your system PATH?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Well here's the thing, Android studio has it's own gradle plugin in it right? I did try to separately download the latest version of gradle from it's website (gradle-2.1) and added that to the path variable. It is still not working. Giving the same error. I have also edited the question a bit too.

Comment: @Faizan - your link is is broken